# Eclipse : Maven - context menu does not display the option "Search dependency for..."

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jboss, dependencies

I downloaded a fresh copy of Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers (eclipse-jee-luna-SR1a-win32-x86_64.zip).

I created a new Maven project (J2EE 1.4 web application archetype) in a new Workspace. When trying to add a class, for example - RestClient - the Eclipse displays error (RestClient cannot be resolved to a type) and the context menu does not display the option "Search dependency for RestClient", as it appears in various videos such as "Adding Project Dependencies in m2eclipse (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H8QdjyCB8Nw)".

Snapshot from video: [Eclipse Maven Search Dependency](http://alltrix.com.br/files/pics/eclipse-maven-search-dependency.PNG)

The same behavior also occurs in fresh copy of JBoss Developer Studio (Version: 8.0.0.GA).

Is there a way to fix that? Thanxs!!!

Comment: Open the progress view when Eclipse starts. Do you see any entry which says "Updating Maven index from Central" or similar? In Preferences -> Maven, is the option "Download repository index on startup" enabled?

Comment: Yes ... I can see the update status and also the option "Download repository index on startup" is enabled.

Comment: I've tried to do the following: Open your "Maven Repositories" view. Open Global Repositories and right-click on central. Enable full index and rebuild, ... and the same thing. It seems very strange lack of item in the context menu on a fresy copy. The shortcut CTRL + SHIFT + T also does not result in anything.

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+T only shows types on the classpath. That will start to work after the dependency has been added **and** downloaded. Can you browse the content of the repository in the "Maven Repositories" view?

Comment: Can you check whether "Enable Full Index" is enabled for the repo in the view?

Comment: If what I understand, yes ... is enabled. Snapshot [link] (http://alltrix.com.br/files/pics/Capture.PNG)

Comment: I just tried; the index for classes can be downloaded but there is no way to get this index inside of Eclipse (or I couldn't find one). So it seems my answer is still correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature has been removed in 2011: https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/m2e-users/msg01130.html

Go to http://search.maven.org and use `fc:"name-of-class"` i.e. `fc:"RestClient"`

Note: The search is quite slow; use Google instead :-)

Comment: Although slightly change the original subject, as it was removed this feature, which is the most efficient way to manage dependencies in Eclipe Luna? Editing directly in the POM?

Comment: If you know the name of the dependency, you can select "Add Dependency" in the Maven menu of the project or you get this menu item when you use the context menu in an open POM editor.